# Can a UIAlertView pass a string and an int through a delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

I have a UIAlertView (several, in fact), and I'm using the method `-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView  clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` to trigger an action if the user doesn't press cancel. Here's my code:

```
- (void)doStuff {   
        // complicated time consuming code here to produce:
        NSString *mySecretString = [self complicatedRoutine];
        int myInt = [self otherComplicatedRoutine];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"HERE'S THE STUFF" 
                                                        message:myPublicString // derived from mySecretString
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Go On", nil];
        [alert setTag:3];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];        
    }
```

and then what I would like to do would be the following:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView 
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        if ([alertView tag] == 3) {
                        NSLog(@"%d: %@",myInt,mySecretString);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this method doesn't know about `mySecretString` or `myInt`. I definitely don't want to recalculate them, and I don't want to store them as properties since `-(void)doStuff` is rarely, if ever, called. Is there a way to add this extra information to the UIAlertView to avoid recalculating or storing `mySecretString` and `myInt`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably the quickest way to associate an object with an arbitrary other object is to use `objc_setAssociatedObject`. To use it correctly, you need an arbitrary `void *` to use as a key; the usual way to do that is to declare a `static char fooKey` globally in your .m file and use `&fooKey` as the key.

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(alertView, &secretStringKey, mySecretString, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
objc_setAssociatedObject(alertView, &intKey, [NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

Then use `objc_getAssociatedObject` to retrieve the objects later.

```
NSString *mySecretString = objc_getAssociatedObject(alertView, &secretStringKey);
int myInt = [objc_getAssociatedObject(alertView, &intKey) intValue];
```

Using OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN, the values will be retained while attached to the `alertView` and then automatically released when `alertView` is deallocated.

Comment: This is so far the best and cleanest way.. Remember to add #import <objc/runtime.h> to use it.