# Access UITableViewCell from UIAlertView in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uialertview

I have a delete button inside a UITableView cell. The function of this button is to delete the content of that specific cell out of Core Data. This process cannot be undone; so, I added UIAlertView to let users confirm their decision before proceeding into deletion.

It seems that I need to code all the deletion logic inside...

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

However, this is a delegate method. The Indexpath of the table cell is missing? How do I access the UITableViewCell data after the UIAlertView button is clicked?

One of the idea I have in mind now is to traverse up using `alertview.superview` until I find UITableViewCell, and access its indexPath property. But this does not seem to be elegant. Should there should be another way to fix this issue?

Comment: are you using custom cell?

Comment: It is good practice that accept answers if you are satisfied any of one

Comment: Yep, it's a custom cell. Right now, passing the indexPath value into an intermediate variable seems to be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `UIAlertView` is modal I don't see any problems in saving the indexPath of the `UITableViewCell` before presenting the `UIAlertView` in a (global) variable (and maybe clearing that variable in `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` (just to be on the safe side).
At least this is what I did when I had this issue.

ps. It's far from best practice but as long as you do some basic checks you should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Use Associated Objects. It is described in more detail here [Associated Objects](http://blog.andymatuschak.org/post/173646741/your-new-friends-obj-c-associated-objects)

To set the object you use use:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(alert, &key, userCode, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

And To get the object.

```
SOCode *userCode = objc_getAssociatedObject(alertView, &key);
```

Never forget to import `<objc/runtime.h>` and You also need to add `static char key`; so that it is in the scope of both methods.

**Reference:**
[Can a UIAlertView pass a string and an int through a delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439560/can-a-uialertview-pass-a-string-and-an-int-through-a-delegate)

Comment: For more information go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439560/can-a-uialertview-pass-a-string-and-an-int-through-a-delegate